# How to reset value

Tags: javascript

If I clicked the button with value of 100 the result is 100 and it will display on the input field, if I clicked the reset button it will cleared the field. But the problem is if I clicked again the button with value of 100 the result will be now 200.

```
function resultreset() {
    document.getElementById("result").reset();
}
```

I expect the reset button will reset (back to zero) the result in the input field, but it's just clearing it.

Comment: so changed its value back to 0 on click, if that doesnt bother you

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] so we can see what goes wrong.

Comment: Please provide the whole code involved.

Comment: What field is "cleared" and what field is "now 200"? You need to show ([edit] into your question) the relevant part of your html

Answer (score 0):

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) on `HTMLFormElement.reset()`:

> The HTMLFormElement.reset() method restores a form element's default values. This method does the same thing as clicking the form's reset button.

The default value is not 0, but an empty string. If you want the default value to be 0, you have to say so explicitly in the HTML, eg with

```
<input value="0">
```

```js
function resultreset() {
    document.getElementById("result").reset();
}

button.onclick = resultreset;
```

```html
<form id="result">
  <input value="0">
</form>
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Comment: If you reread the question you most likely will see this doesn't answer it. If OP's first button click renders 100, so will a second, after a reset, but it instead show 200. That probably mean OP has a counter somewhere else, which is not being reset.

Answer (score -1):

If you put this into form tag it will work properly Because you can not use reset() method on input tag it will definitely throw an error.

Your output can be achieved in two ways:

**First using form**

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
 
 <input type="text" name="lname" value="0">
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset ">
</form>
```

**Second using *defaulValue* property**

`document.getElementById("input_id").defaultValue = "0";`